# Getting the turning points of a curve

Tags: r, time-series, curve

The following curve was created using R from data (downloadable [data1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fSDO9QnafWa4u0Q3PNUyJBomE02DZbxP/view?usp=sharing),[data2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LuJu27DQoJPokHkfe7XRA6USovISqeDi/view?usp=sharing)) obtained from a sensor.

[image]

The X-axis is time in milliseconds and Y-axis is binding response between two antibodies (say AB.2 & AB.3). I am algorithmically  trying to get the starting and ending time point of different phases of the curve (marked by vertical lines) specifically the last phase (marked by blue vertical line). Some of the curves have vertical U-shaped starting or tailing parts that should be removed too.
The curve was  created using the following code:

```
Load(data2)
ggplot(ff3,aes(x=time,y= bindingValue,color= SecondAb)) + geom_line()+
geom_point()+theme(legend.position="none")+ 
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(175,529.7782,1257.4810,1566.2750,1980),
     color=c('black' ,'black','black','blue','blue'))
```

For my first problem I tried the `changepoint` package but it gives me too many change points. I tried to get the time points using the following two functions but it is not getting the right turning points correctly as it is finding the local minima and adjusting the threshold is another problem as I have thousands of curves from different data set.

```
inflect <- function(x, threshold = 1){
up   <- sapply(1:threshold, function(n) c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n)))
down <-  sapply(-1:-threshold, function(n) c(rep(NA,abs(n)), x[- 
seq(length(x), length(x) - abs(n) + 1)]))
a    <- cbind(x,up,down)
minima = which(apply(a, 1, min) == a[,1])
as.vector(minima)
}

transition_values <-function(dd){
threshold<-ceiling(max(dd$time,na.rm = T)/60)
w <-dd$time[inflect(dd$bindingValue,threshold)]
w
}
```

Calling the function gives me :

```
transition_values(ff3)
# 99.16498  529.77820  895.91300 1257.48100 (Here getting two points correct here)
```

How can I get the exact turning points programmatically?

For my second problem (removing the U shaped part of the curve) I tried to remove the outliers using the following code but I am looking for something more efficient

```
remove_outliers <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
y <- x
y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] <- NA
y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- NA
y
}
```

Comment: This looks like you're trying to find discontinuities in the first derivative rather than "turning points" (which most would assume means inflection points, i.e. those points where your curve changes curvature, i.e. points where second derivative changes sign).

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Can you please give me some direction how to approach the problem with finding discontinuities in the first derivative. I tried diff() but could not get around with it. Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with R, but I do see that https://www.r-project.org/help.html lists a few other avenues that I can recommend using in addition to this question on Stackoverflow.